# Delete file older than 30 days

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have been trying to Delete file in a Folder which is Older than 30 days,
below is the code, in which I am trying to get the File save date, but its not returning clearly.

[image: I have attached the image]

```
char c_szText[_MAX_PATH];
wcstombs(c_szText, username, wcslen(username) + 1);

std::string Fstr("c:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Test\\*");
Fstr.replace(9, 8, c_szText);

const time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm* tl = localtime(&t);

WIN32_FIND_DATA info;
HANDLE hp;
hp = FindFirstFile(str2.c_str(), &info);
do
{
    FILETIME ftCreate, ftAccess, ftWrite;
    SYSTEMTIME stUTC, stLocal;
    DWORD dwRet;

    LPTSTR lpszString;
    GetFileTime(hp, &ftCreate, &ftAccess, &ftWrite);
    // Convert the last-write time to local time.
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftWrite, &stUTC);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &stUTC, &stLocal);
    if (tl->tm_year + 1900 > stLocal.wYear)
    { 
        DeleteFile(info.cFileName);
    }
    else if ((tl->tm_mon - ((stLocal.wMonth) - 1)) > 1)
    {
        DeleteFile(info.cFileName);
    }
    else if(tl->tm_mon > ((stLocal.wMonth)-1))
    {
        if(tl->tm_mday <= stLocal.wDay)
        { 
            DeleteFile(info.cFileName);
        }
    }
} while (FindNextFile(hp, &info));
FindClose(hp);
```

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not returning clearly"?  What values are you getting?  Where do you initialize `t1`.  Please reduce your problem as much as possible.  For example, make the program take a single file on the command line, and just print the last write time, then tell us what values you get, and what values you want.  We need a [mcve]

Comment: Have you considered doing some debugging? Wouldn't that be easier for you to do than for us to do?

Comment: And are you aware that your code performs no error checking at all. That's a huge mistake, seemingly made by most beginners. Don't omit error checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert your Unicode strings to MBCS.  Use the `WCHAR`-based `FindFirstFileW()` function instead of the `TCHAR`-based `FindFirstFile()` function.

There is no need to convert times to the local timezone.  File times are expressed in UTC, and you can retrieve the current system clock time in UTC.  Then you can compare the two values without converting them.

Also, you are not retrieving the file times correctly.  You are passing the wrong `HANDLE` to `GetFileTime()`.  It expects a handle to an open file, but you are passing it a handle to a search object instead.  The `WIN32_FIND_DATA` already contains the file times, you don't need to retrieve them manually.

Also, you are passing only the file name to `DeleteFile()`.  The `WIN32_FIND_DATA` only contains the filename, not the folder path.  If you don't prepend the folder path, `DeleteFile()` will interpret the file name as relative to the calling process's Current Working Directory, which is not guaranteed (or likely) to be in the folder you are expecting.

Try something more like this:

```
/* helper macros, courtesy of MSDN:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/188768/info-working-with-the-filetime-structure
*/
#define FT_SECOND ((INT64) 10000000)
#define FT_MINUTE (60 * FT_SECOND)
#define FT_HOUR   (60 * FT_MINUTE)
#define FT_DAY    (24 * FT_HOUR)

/*
Note: you really should be using SHGetFilePath() or SHGetKnownFolderPath()
to retrieve a given user's APPDATA folder location...
*/
std::wstring Ffolder = L"c:\\Users\\" + std::wstring(username) + L"\\AppData\\Test\\";
/* alternatively:
std::wostringstream wos;
wos << L"c:\\Users\\" << username << L"\\AppData\\Test\\";
std::wstring Ffolder = wos.str();
*/

// get today @ 00:00:00:00 time, in UTC...
SYSTEMTIME stUTC = {0};
GetSystemTime(&stUTC);
stUTC.wHour = stUTC.wMinute = stUTC.wSecond =  stUTC.wMilliseconds = 0;

// subtract 30 days from it...
FILETIME ft30DaysAgo = {0};
ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&stUTC, &ft30DaysAgo);
ul.LowPart = ft30DaysAgo.dwLowDateTime;
ul.HighPart = ft30DaysAgo.dwHighDateTime;
ul.QuadPart -= (30 * FT_DAY);
ft30DaysAgo.dwLowDateTime = ul.LowPart;
ft30DaysAgo.dwHighDateTime = ul.HighPart;

// now search for files...
WIN32_FIND_DATAW info;
HANDLE hp = FindFirstFileW((Ffolder + L"*").c_str(), &info);
if (hp != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        if (
            // process only files...
            ((info.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0) &&
            // that have a last-write time...
            ((info.ftLastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime != 0) || (info.ftLastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime != 0)) &&
            // older than 30 days...
            (CompareFileTime(&(info.ftLastWriteTime), &ft30DaysAgo) < 0)
            )
        {
            // bye bye!!
            DeleteFileW((Ffolder + info.cFileName).c_str());
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hp, &info));
    FindClose(hp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not need to convert `FILETIME` into `SYSTEMTIME`. The `FILETIME` is essentially a `__int64` time value in 100ns units (starting from some reference time), this is exactly what you need for time comparison.

Just get the current time via `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, subtract 30 days from it, and this would be your threshold.

Comment: Since I am beginner, could you please provide a code, where I need to change to achieve the result..

Comment: Since you are a beginner, why not try to learn yourself rather than be spoon fed.

Comment: [INFO: Working with the FILETIME Structure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/188768/info-working-with-the-filetime-structure)